# How can I write a php script to update a file list?

Tags: c#, php

i have a program to update some file from my site and i do all work but i have a problem in
update.php script

my application side update cod is(in C#):

```
    public string[] NeededFiles = { "teknomw3.dll" };
    public string HomePageUrl = "http://se7enclan.ir";
    public string NewsUrl = "http://se7enclan.ir/news";
    public string DownloadUrl = "http://se7enclan.ir/";
    public string UpdateList = "http://se7enclan.ir/update.php?action=list";
    public string UpdateBaseUrl = "http://se7enclan.ir/Update/";
```

and my update directory on my site as you see(all files is here.):

http://se7enclan.ir/Update/

so what script must be in update.php that i can use this:   "update.php?action=list"

this update.php script must work like this site:
http://mw3luncher.netai.net/update.php?action=list

Thank you.

Comment: Your code example is not written in PHP. It's also unclear what your problem is. Are you asking for a complete script to run an executable on the server?

Comment: This questions needs a better title.

Comment: look this code is in my application side and use this address to update files from my site .  i just need a update.php script like this site http://mw3luncher.netai.net/update.php?action=list   in this php script all files listed.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please explain in words what you expect your code to do, show us what is not working and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hmm the script you link (and which code you did not post here) "magically" changes it's output. Just coding while asking means just asking while coding - so actually are you only looking for inspiration? Always directly ask what you want to know.

Comment: my means what php script need to list my files from x directory on my web space (this script need to show files size like that site link i posted

Comment: People here do not even try to understand the question. In fact, a pretty simple question. Our friend @raminesmailinagad just didn't know how to express himself properly. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem man. Here is a solution:

```
<?PHP
  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
       $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry",
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
   }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
?>
```

You can use this function as follows:

```
<?PHP
  // examples for scanning the current directory
  $dirlist = getFileList(".");
  $dirlist = getFileList("./");
?>
```

And to output the results to an HTML page we just loop through the returned array:

```
<?PHP
  // output file list as HTML table
  echo "<table border="1">\n";
  echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th><th>Last Mod.</th></tr>\n";
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</table>\n\n";
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you i used your first script but i get blank page???? when i searched "update.php?action=list"  and output format must be like that:  "iw5sp.exe" "96371a6f01b1e5465e0de0e5bc0c911b"        "4753480"     first file name, second i dont know exactly what is it i think its file Stream, and third size off file.

Comment: Thank you and pleas see my question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869907/how-can-i-add-a-hash-segment-and-remove-this-part-from-output-data

Comment: when i use this cod i get this output data:

./dir.php 1338721029 293 ./echo.php 1338719989 270 ./New Text Document.txt 1338719618 0 ./update.php 1338721316 924

question: i don't want to add this "./" to first for file name in output data! so how i can remove that? question 2:

as you see in output data i have 3 part : "file name","13387....","file size" so Instead of 13387.... i want to add file hash so how can i add a hash segment here?!

question 3: is it possible the php cod check and print file hash himself?